# JQuery Dialog won't display with large dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, modal-dialog

Is there a max data size that a jquery dialog can hold? I have json that's almost 1 mb large that I'm trying to display in a modal dialog. It's been working fine with a small dataset that I read from a file. But a large dataset that I'm actually getting from the request won't display at all - no box, no data, no nothing.

I put a breakpoint in my success code block and everything runs. What could be causing the box not to display?

Comment: How is your data formatted? How are you parsing it? Does it work on Chrome but not on IE?

Comment: Code or it didn't happen! You can use http://livecoding.io to put together a long demo - dump your json in the "JSON" tab.

Comment: 1MB of json? probably just forgot to unescape a " :P